# post_max_size resets to default

Tags: php, nginx, freebsd

**Scenario:** Installed an adult tubescript for a pornsite. Keeps having problems with file upload over 8MB

I figured it has something to do with php.ini, so I checked and changed it to

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_size = 200M
```

On .htaccess of the script, there is these two lines:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 1000M
```

but when I check using phpinfo(), post_max_size is still 8M and I still can't upload anything over 8MB. I've been working on this for 3 days now and I really can't figure it out.

What could possibly be causing this?

> Dedicated Server: FreeBSD 8.2, Nginx 1.0.6, PHP 5.2

Comment: As with any mysterious changing .ini values: you're either changing the values in the wrong .ini file, or there's an override elsewhere (httpd.conf, .htaccess, etc....) down the rendering chain.

Comment: yes I have considered those, but there are no other php.ini file in the server and no active httpd.conf either.
and phpinfo(); points to the only php.ini present: **/usr/local/etc/php.ini**.

also, on .httaccess, post_max_size is set to 1000M

Comment: That does sound odd. Do you see the same information when you run `php --info` from CLI.

Comment: @piddl0r no, it's **post_max_size = 200**, does it mean that there is something resetting the php config on the webroot? what kind of file should I look for? I have checked all .htaccess on webroot and they don't have anything relevant to post_max_size

Comment: @bonesnatch That would imply that there two copies of PHP on the server, when you get info in the CLI it may point to a different ini file.

Comment: @piddl0r yes it seems to be the case, I'm now looking for that extra PHP...
is there a way to point php to use **/usr/local/etc/php.ini** instead?

Comment: tried ini_set('post_max_size','200M'); still no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that Nginx needs a php feeder/loader: fastcgi

In my case it's **spawn-fcgi**

here's how I fixed it

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/spawn-fcgi restart
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/nginx restart
```

Thanks for the replies.
Credits to DarkZenith for the pointers.